# I would like that a calculation happens in the VBA memory and after the calculation happens only the values to be pasted in a row in MS EXcel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like that a calculation happens in the VBA memory and after the calculation happens only the values to be pasted in a row in MS Excel.

As you can see from the code below the calculation happens within the cell and it is time consuming, because the data is huge.

Here is my code.

```
Sub SumIFF()

 Dim k As Integer
 Dim l As Integer
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet

 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Input") 'whatever you worksheet is

      k = 2 'this is the first row where your data will output
      l = 2 'this is the first row where you want to check for data

Do Until Range("A" & l) = "" 'This will loop until column U is empty, set the column to whatever you want but it cannot have blanks in it, or it will stop looping. Choose a column that is always going to have data in it.

        ws1.Range("X" & k).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R2C21:RC[-3],RC[-3],R2C22:RC[-2])" 'reference SUMIF formula 


        k = k + 1 'Advances k and l when there is a matching case
        l = l + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before performing the calculation, and afterwards restore with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Answer (score 0):

Set Application.ScreenUpdating = False before performing the calculation, and afterwards restore with Application.ScreenUpdating = True –  Pieter Geerkens Jul 15 at 22:05